# Using .split() to transform string to array (Improvement needed)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to use JavaScript to transform this string

`.txt|.pdf|.xls|.xlsx|.doc|.docx|.rtf|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif`

into this array

`["txt", "pdf", "xls", "xlsx", "doc", "docx", "rtf", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"]`

But it gives me this

`[".txt", "pdf", "xls", "xlsx", "doc", "docx", "rtf", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"]`

It keeps the dot in front of first element. What can I do since I don't know regex? Here is my code:

```
let fileTypes = string.split('|.');
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how? please explain

Comment: @Gab: It can be easily done with `String.match()`: `'.txt|.pdf|.xls|.xlsx|.doc|.docx|.rtf|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif'.match(/\w+/g);` --> `["txt", "pdf", "xls", "xlsx", "doc", "docx", "rtf", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var string = '.txt|.pdf|.xls|.xlsx|.doc|.docx|.rtf|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif';

var arr = string.replace(/\./g,'').split('|');
```

This will first strip all of the dots, then split on the `|`. Separating by the pipe is all that matters... So it will take a more flexible string if that matters.

Answer (score 6):

The problem only seems to be the first dot, so you could just do

```
s = ".txt|.pdf|.xls|.xlsx|.doc|.docx|.rtf|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif"
s.substr(1).split("|.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The first dot isn't matched by your `split()`. A simple solution would be to replace it first:

```
let fileTypes = string.replace(/^\./,'').split('|.');
```

```js
var string = '.txt|.pdf|.xls|.xlsx|.doc|.docx|.rtf|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif';

var fileTypes = string.replace(/^\./,'').split('|.');

console.log(fileTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the functions .split and .join like so:

```js
var typeFile = ".txt|.pdf|.xls|.xlsx|.doc|.docx|.rtf|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif";

var newstring =  typeFile.split('.').join('').split('|');
console.log(newstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

The substr() method extracts parts of a string, beginning at the character at the specified position, and returns the specified number of characters.So it would be better if you first use substr from the first position and then either use split() as you have done.

s = ".txt|.pdf|.xls|.xlsx|.doc|.docx|.rtf|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif"